# Ending program when Newline is entered

Tags: c

I am looking to understand how to make the program break from a while loop when the user has entered nothing into the command line. The program should only continue looping when the user has entered elements into the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int ch;

while ((ch == getchar()) != '\n')  // read one char:  quit?
    putchar(toupper(ch));        // upper-case character and print

return 123 ;                     // Unix: check with: echo $?
```

Comment: Can use `fgets()` and array of `char`? Or are limited to `getchar()`?

Comment: Basic novice tips: 1. Always check for IO errors or EOF! In this case check if `getchar()` returns `EOF`. 2. Enable compiler warnings, `-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* and *clang*, `/W4` for MSVC. Then fix warnings in your own code! 3. Use `{}`, even when you don't have to, and use auto-indent or auto-format/beautify on your code.

Answer (score 1):

With this code you're not assigning the `ch` variable but checking if it's equal to the value returned by `getchar()`.
This way your while loop *never stops iterating*, since `(ch == getchar())` is always `0` (false) and `0 != '\n'` (`'\n'` value is `10`).

You probably want to **change** `(ch == getchar())` to **`(ch = getchar())`**, so you can update `ch` with the value entered by input.

I suggest you to **turn on your compiler warnings**, so it will tell you stuff like that and help you understand and fix it. I think you might find the following thread extremely useful: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Example `gcc` with flags `-Wall -Wextra` (https://godbolt.org/z/n6vG6f7Gv):

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
<source>:7:26: warning: comparison of constant '10' with boolean expression is always true [-Wbool-compare]
    7 | while ((ch == getchar()) != '\n')  // read one char:  quit?
      |                          ^~
<source>:8:5: warning: 'ch' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    8 |     putchar(toupper(ch));        // upper-case character and print
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

Moreover, it's a **good practice** to `return 0` at the end of `main` function, which indicates that the program ended correctly, and eventually make it return something else in case errors occur.

Comment: There should also be a warning about using `ch` uninitialized, which should also reveal that nothing is ever assigned to it.

Comment: This breaks regardless to the first statement of input, but the purpose is supposed to break 'only' if the user has enter a empty line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that '\n' is at the first position of the line. Using [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) is a simpler solution as it returns the entire null terminated read line with the '\n' at the end:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  char line[256];
  size_t l;
  size_t i;

  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {

    l = strlen(line);

    // '\n' is the last char in line[]

    // If empty line (only '\n')
    if (l == 1) {

      break;

    }

    for (i = 0; i < l; i ++) {
      putchar(toupper(line[i]));
    }

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Examples of executions:

```
$ ./readl
$ ./readl 
azerty is not qwerty
AZERTY IS NOT QWERTY
     word preceded by spaces
     WORD PRECEDED BY SPACES
```